# How to iterate over an struct array passed by a function in c?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

I have been trying to iterate over a struct array, but for some reason it only goes through once. I am still trying to get the hang of c and its use of pointers. For the function, I have to use the **books array and iterate over it. For instance, I need to return how many books that cost less than $50 dollars. I don't know why it is iterating through only once.. When I use a print statement to check the "number_of_books", I get five which is the correct size of the array. Help would be appreciated!

```
// calling the function in main as : int b = get_cost(books, 50)

int get_cost(book **books, int cost){

    int get_book_total = 0; 
                                                                                                 
    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_books; i++){                                                                                           
          if(books[i]->cost < cost){
                 get_book_total++;
          }                                                                                                            
          return get_book_total; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **return** statement is in your **for** loop, so your function returns after the first iteration.

Comment: If I move the return statement out of the for loop, I get a Segmentation error.

Comment: What's the value of  **number_of_books** ? Make sure it's the actual size of your array.

Comment: It is holding 5 elements.  I am using a static array which holds 100.

Comment: It is part of a project, so I wouldn't be able to. I'm not sure why such a simple function like this wouldn't work so I am assuming there is something small that is hidden within my code that is causing this..

Comment: The segmentation fault most probably occurs because **number_of_books** is greater than the actual size of the array, so your **for loop** tries to access memory not allocated for the array. But without seeing more of your code I can't help you.

Comment: I understand. Thank you your help. I'll check that out.

Comment: I made a small working example from what I see of your code : https://github.com/guimauveb/so-answers/blob/main/answers/64415768/books.c (yes I've got some free time)

Comment: Thank you for doing so. I just looked it over and while looking at your code, I realized something involving my main array and my array in my .c file. I am trying to figure it out now and I think I will get it, so THANK YOU so much for doing all that. I really appreciate it!